# C++ what's difference of param with const and without const in class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this code but compilation failed:

```
class TextBlock
{
    public:
        TextBlock(std::string &s)
        {
            text = s;
        }

    private:
        std::string text;
};
int main()
{
    TextBlock tb("Hello");
    std::cout<< tb[0] << std::endl ;
}
```

why when the constructor is `TextBlock(const std::string &s)` the above code can compile success ?

Comment: Temporary cannot bind to non-const (l-value) reference.

Comment: sloppy speaking you need a string somewhere, a reference is just a reference. If the reference is `const` then the function is fine with taking a temporary because anyhow it wont be modified. Passing a temporary to a function that expects a non-const reference is pointless because you cannot observe the modifications, hence it makes sense that this is an error

Answer (score 1):

the constructor is specting a ref to a string do instead:

```
std::string  x{"hello"};
TextBlock tb(x);
```